# How to set a property of an item in nested array using ImmutableJS Map?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Have to avoid any mutations in `state` object. Can you advice, how to change row text by rowId using `Immutable.Map()`?

`setIn` function doesn't seems to be working with Map in this case?

```
var state = {
    pages: [
        {
            tiles: [
                {
                    rows: [
                        {rowId: 'row1', text: 'text1'},
                        {rowId: 'row2', text: 'text2'},
                        {rowId: 'row3', text: 'text3'}
                        //...
                    ]
                },
                {
                    //...
                }
                //...
            ]
        }
        //...
    ]
};

function onRowUpdateAction(state, rowId, rowText) {
        var map = Immutable.Map(state);
        //TODO: Update row text by row id ?

        return map.toObject();
}
var newState = onRowUpdateAction(state, 'row2', 'updatedText');
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`setIn` plays nicely with both Maps and Lists. From what you wrote the problem seems to be, that you are not actually dealing with deeply immutable structure. Note, that creating `immutable.Map` such as

```
immutable.Map({a: {b: 'c'}})
```

creates immutable Map with key `'a'` and value `{b: 'c'}` (as a plain JS object)! No wonder, that immutable's `getIn` does not work with it.

To make structure deeply immutable, use `immutable.fromJS` (this is probably what you intended to use).